# Electric breaker box not producing 220

Tags: electrical

Electrical box not producing 220. All 220 appliances are only pulling 110 happened last night still going on today never happened before.

Comment: 220? most countries its 230...

Comment: Really need more detail about the situation - RCD, MCB sockets etc

Comment: You know what a 2-pole breaker looks like?  Sorta like two 1-poles but with a handle-tie connecting them?  **Shut all those off in your panel**.  Do a bunch of circuits now lose power entirely?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. As the others have suggested, we'll need more info before we can help you.

Comment: Are there any 120V circuits without power, for that matter?

Comment: You appear to have lost a phase.  I assume you have 110/220V with a neutral?  Is your main disconnect of an old type that uses fuses?  What was your method of checking voltage to the appliances?

Comment: Is there a main breaker out side the house at the power meter? I had one side of mine go bad and lost half the voltage

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you lost a phase from your utility.  If you have overhead supply, that is the likeliest possibility.  You could open up the panel and check the breakers, but if you call the power company, the visit will be free and fast (assuming you didn't just have a windstorm, ice storm or other mass-outage event).

Ideally you would get all dead 240V appliances and all dead 120V appliances on one pole.  What actually happens is (from the 240V appliance's perspective) one leg is connected to neutral *via* your 120V appliances, and (from the 120V appliance's perspective) their hot wire is connected to the other hot wire *via* the 240V appliances.